# Pulling all rows with the date that is directly less than the date of interest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that has these fields:

| Name | Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| John | 5-29-10 | Y |
| Rick | 7-14-12 | N |
| Rick | 9-02-13 | N |
| Rick | 4-21-15 | Y |
| Rick | 6-21-17 | N |

I want to pull all the rows with the first date smaller than the date with a "Y" in the Flag column. So for John, I want to pull all 3 rows with the date 5-28-10. However for Rick, I only want to pull the row with the date 9-02-13.

So the desired output would look like:

| Name | Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| John | 5-28-10 | N |
| Rick | 9-02-13 | N |

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: please provide desired output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` as follows:

```
Select t.* from
(Select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by name order by date desc) as dr
  From your_table t
 Where t.date < (select min(tt.date)
                from your_table tt
                where tt.name = t.name 
                  and tt.flag = 'Y') ) t
  Where t.dr = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This query worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.flag <> 'Y' and
      t.date < (select min(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name and t.flag = 'Y'
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is using a subquery in an `APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT YT.[Name],
       YT.[Date],
       YT.[Flag]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ca.[Date]
                  FROM dbo.YourTable ca
                  WHERE ca.[Name] = YT.[Name] --HOpefully you have an ID, a person's name isn't unique. Trust me.
                    AND ca.Flag = 'Y'
                  ORDER BY ca.[Date] ASC) D
WHERE YT.[Date] < D.[Date];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking to subquery (in a CTE) for rows where the Flag='Y'.  Then compare the CTE to the source table by [Name] where the source [Date] is less than the 'Y' row [Date].

```
with flag_cte([Name], [Date], Flag) as (
    select * 
    from tTable
    where Flag='Y')
select t.*
from tTable t
     join flag_cte f on t.[Name]=f.[Name]
                        and t.[Date]<f.[Date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach with DENSE_RANK that uses windowed MAX to determine “has there been a Y flag yet?”

This may or may not give you what you want for names with no flag=Y row, in case that is a possibility.

```
with F1(name,d,flag,mf) as (
  select
    name,
    d,
    flag,
    max(flag) over (partition by name order by d) as mf
  from T
), F2(name,d,flag,dr) as (
  select
    name,
    d,
    flag,
    dense_rank() over (partition by name order by d desc) as dr
  from F1
  where mf='N'
)
  select name, d, flag
  from F2
  where dr=1;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/223a0b/4).